# How can you programmatically resize a column using react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

When using [react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table), you can specify `defaultColumn` to give default column widths as

```
  const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      Header: DefaultHeader,
      Cell: DefaultCell,
      width: 200,
    }),
    []
  );
```

How can I programmatically change that `200` some time later? If I were to do

```
  const defaultColumn = {
      Header: DefaultHeader,
      Cell: DefaultCell,
      width: 200,
    };
```

and later update that `200`, then it has no effect, as `react-table` only reads those values on initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a `useMemo` hook, you can use the dependencies array passed to it.

You can define `defaultColumn` like this:

```
  const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      Header: DefaultHeader,
      Cell: DefaultCell,
      width: colWidth,
    }),
    [colWidth]
  );
```

Where `colWidth` is the width you want to pass to the creation of defaultColumn.
Now, when colWidth changes, `useMemo` will create the new `defaultColumn` on render.

(Note that `colWidth` is a variable in the same scope of `defaultColumn`).

Comment: Sorry, the `useMemo` made the question a little misleading. Even without that, changes to width do not update it